# Time Domain to Frequency domain with DSP

Tags: c++, transform, signal-processing, energy

I try to convert my time domain data to frequency domain data with Aquila DSP library.After that I calculate energy, mean and other coefficients with same library. As a sample i create a vector and `Aquila::SignalSource` like that

```
std::vector<double> xaxis = { 1,5,3,7,5,9,7,11 };
Aquila::SignalSource signalSource(xaxis);     
double energy = Aquila::energy(signalSource);
```

I calculate energy of that signal but i think this value for time domain.

How to calculate fft energy ?

Comment: I'm sure your library comes with [documentation](http://aquila-dsp.org/docs/). You should consult it.

Comment: I am not  familiar with signal processing.  I looked examples and read documentation but i did not find anything. Maybe some terms in the documnetation are meaningless for me.

Comment: total energy is the same in both the time and frequency domains

Comment: I try to solve this problem with matlab and results are different. Time domain energy =360 and fft energy = 2880.

Comment: Your FFT is not normalized, so performing the FFT multiplies the energy by the number of samples.